# Expression in backticks with Perl `'cmd'.join ...`

Tags: perl

I would like to send the remaining `@ARGV` to `foo`. I currently do this:

```
my $cmd = 'foo '.join ' ', @ARGV;
my $out = `$cmd`;
```

Is there possible to do it in one line? For instance with a non-existent `e` option:

```
my $out = qx/'foo'.join ' ', @ARGV/e;
```

In a more general case I might want to do this:

```
my $out = qx/'foo?.join(' ', keys %hash)/e;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin [`readpipe`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#readpipe) function is what is at the back end of backticks/`qx()` calls, so you can use that directly:

```
my $out = readpipe('foo' . join ' ', @ARGV);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to assemble the command prior to running it. The `qx()` operator (aliased by the backticks) interpolates.

```
 perl -e 'print `echo @ARGV`' foo bar
```

or in your script:

```
my $out = `foo @ARGV`
```

What "optional" says about `qx` and interpolation is right: Beware that double interpolation might bite you and it's prone to security issues!

Regarding your update: Try

```
perl -e '%h = (foo=>1,bar=>2); print `echo @{[keys %h]}`'
```

That constructs an anonymous arrayref and immediately dereferrences it. Hashes don't interpolate but this array context allows arbitrary Perl code producing a list. Also I'm pretty sure the compiler recognized this idiom and removes the arrayref (de)dereferrence during optimization.

But that is really ugly, nearly unreadable from my point of view. I'd rather recommend:

```
my @keys = keys %hash;
my $cmd  = "foo @keys";
my $out  = `$cmd`;
```

Hint: storing the command in a dedicated variable makes logging executes commands easier what is *really* desirable.

Comment: Nice to know. I should have mentioned that in my real example I need to do `qx/foo ''keys %hash''/`. I've learned something anyway :)

Comment: @coin So please update your question accordingly. I don't right understand the use of the single quotes. Can you add expected input and output samples?

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
my $out = capture_this_command( 'foo', @ARGV );

sub capture_this_command {
    use Capture::Tiny qw/ capture /;
##    local %ENV;
##    delete @ENV{'PATH', 'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};
##    $ENV{'PATH'} = '/bin:/usr/bin';

    my @cmd = @_;
    my( $stdout, $stderr, $exit ) = capture { 
        system { $cmd[0] } @cmd;
    };;

    if( $exit ){
        die "got the exit( $exit ) and stderr: $stderr\n   ";
    } elsif( $stderr ){
        warn "got stderr: $stderr\n   ";
    }

    return $stdout;
}
```

**update:**
qx// is double quotes, it interpolates, so everything perlintro/perlsyn/*perlquote* say about that goes, but also, remember, qx// calls your shell (to see which one you have `perl -V:sh`) and shells have their own interpolation

So you could write `my $out = qx/foo @ARGV/;` but its subject to interpolation, first by perl, then by whatever shell you're invoking

Comment: Well, this is a bit bigger than one-line, but thank anyway :)

Comment: Looks like one line to me :) `my $out = capture_this_command( 'foo', @ARGV );`

Comment: If you ignore the additional subroutine, yes you're right :)

Comment: You could always use https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny#capture_stdout directly